# How to suppress warning in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using following code to load R dataset in python:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri   # MANY WARNINGS COME AT THIS STEP.
pandas2ri.ri2py(r['iris'])               # this works ok.
```

The code works all right but I get lot of warnings in following form as first statement is executed:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Loading required package: survival
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
```

They seem to be due to loading of my .Rprofile file (since survival package is not my code here). How can I suppress these warnings either directly or by preventing loading of .Rprofile file? Thanks for your help.